# Entity Framework does not return proxy when object as added in the same context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class:

```
public class Company
{    
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CreatedById { get; set; }    
    public virtual Users CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I am adding new object of `Company` class to context and setting `CreatedById` field:

```
var newCompanyId = Guid.NewGuid();
var company = new Company();
company.Id = newCompanyId;
company.CreatedById = someId;

Context.Set<Company>().Add(company);
```

Then I am using the same context to retrieve company:

```
var retrievedCompany = Context.Set<Company>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == newCompanyId);
```

`retrievedCompany` has type `Company` and it is not dynamic proxy, so navigation property called `CreatedBy` does not work.

Is it possible to get proxy instead?

Comment: Do you don't turn off proxy creation:`context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make Entity Framework aware of your new entity by using `Create()` instead of just instantiating an instance of `Company`. You can use

```
var company = ContextSet<Company>().Create();
```

to create a new instance of the `Company` type then add that to the context. When you add the object to the context, it will attempt to fetch the navigation property automatically so it should be populated before `SaveChanges()`.

Then you'll be able to use that navigation property at a later time within the same instance of the context.